# Difference between Factory_Girl linting and Rspec's expect to be_valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, automated-tests, factory-bot

What is the difference between **testing factories** with **[Factory_Girl Lint]**[1](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki/Testing-all-Factories-(with-RSpec)), and **RSpec's**:

```
...
it 'has a valid factory' do 
  expect(build(:foo)).to be_valid
end
...
```

Am I correct to assume that  **Factory_Girl Lint** checking for schema / db level validations like `null: false`, and the **Rspec's expect to be_valid** checks for model-level validations like `validates_presence_of`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rspec's `be_valid` expectation essentially just calls `valid?` on the model, and as such only tests ActiveRecord validations. However, I believe that FactoryGirl's lint method will not only create the model but save it as well and as such tests both the ActiveRecord validations and any database-level validations (that aren't already covered by the ActiveRecord validations). Note that if saving a model instance fails due to an ActiveRecord validation violation then that model won't be tested against the database until you fix the issue and test again.

On a practical level, I find that Rspec's `be_valid` expectation is most useful when testing specific violations of validity. For example:

```
some_record = SomeRecord.new(...minimum set of valid properties...)
some_record.property = 'invalid value'
some_record.should_not be_valid
some_record.error.full_messages.should include('expected error for the given property')
```

Whereas FactoryGirl's lint method is most useful for testing that you have correctly built your factories.

Comment: Thanks! This means that I would want to have both, Lint and Rspec expectations present in my test suite to make sure my factories are constructed correctly and my models pass ActiveRecord and DB level validations. Correct?

Comment: @Dimitry_N Yes, exactly.